# Wordpress returning double values for get_author

Tags: wordpress

I took over a Wordpress site and noticed a weird bug. Despite echoing a single get_author() on posts, the pages are displaying doubles for the author (i.e., AuthorAuthor).

Any idea why this may happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function may display the content already so echoing it will produce the name twice. Remove the echo, or use `get_the_author()`.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue. Used get_the_author instead. Thanks!